# What are more formal synonyms for "telephone tag"?

Tags: synonyms

Here is [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_tag):

> Phone tag is a phenomenon in which two parties attempt to contact each other by telephone, but neither is able to get a hold of the other for a conversation. Both parties may leave a message on the answering machine or voicemail of the other, and request a call back. This continues for a period of time, often with the two parties exchanging attempts to have a real-time conversation.[1] The name derives from the playground game tag, where players chase one another in turn.

Comment: In what sense do you mean 'tag'? I am assuming you mean it as a verb (as you offset it against a noun alternative), but then what is "telephone tag"? Is it a game? (As a noun, a telephone tag would be a badge or label attached to a telephone, I guess)

Comment: Telephone tag: a situation in which two people keep trying to call each other on the telephone but are unable to reach each other

Comment: Mutual unavailability

Comment: @mplungjan and there was me about to give an answer based on taking "telephone tag" to mean a situation where some point of discussion leads to the members of a group constantly phoning each other as they try to keep themselves and each other current with unfolding events. That's how I've used it, but since your definition would also hold, let's see what LePressentiment has to say.

Comment: Ah :) A world of telecom opening up :) I can see the link with "back-and-forth" in @JonHanna's description, although the mutual unavailability is more recognizable from personal experience. Especially after a connection was broken and you both try to call the other party - at the same time.

Comment: The worst is when the number is engaged because they are talking to my voicemail

Comment: @JonHanna: Please forgive me for any inconvenience. I've updated my OP with the definition.

Comment: Why do you want a more formal term?  I used it for decades at work and never felt the need for a formal term.

Comment: **We keep missing each other**  would be in neutral register.  Better than "We've been playing phone tag" if you don't want to be too casual with the person on the other end of the line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ***Telephone tag:*** a situation in which two people keep trying to call each other on the telephone but are unable to reach each other – mplungjan 10 mins ago

My suggestion: **(Mutual) serial/sequential unavailability**

For the situation I have more often where I call my dad and he is engaged because he concurrently try to reach me I would call
**Mutual (/) concurrent unavailability**

Comment: Or mutually infuriating...

Comment: "Concurrent" doesn't work here, as that implies *simultaneous* unavailability, which doesn't occur with phone tag. "Mutual" also has the same problem, implying that the unavailability is *shared*, when it is actually only one person exhibiting it at a time.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie See update.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, but that's not "phone tag", as that implies there is one person who is "it" who now has the responsibility of calling the other. Phone tag implies a sequential unavailability and a back-and-forth act of calling.

Comment: So my suggestion of serial or sequential is still valid